# How to show promotional Label using custom attribute in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, custom-attributes

I want a custom attribute where If we write anything like "FREE INSTALLATION" It will show on Frontend Product Listing...

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: is it for product base or category?

Comment: The products shown through list.phtml

Comment: yes but you want this information for product or category like for each product if product is having free installation or not some thing like this?

Comment: Hi Ashish, I want this information for products,

Magento will check in all products if custom attribute has some data or not, if it has data then it will show in frontend product listing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to follow the following steps.

1) In your admin navigate to **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes** and add new attribute with following details.

If you want to enter a data from admin then select **Text Field for Catalog Input Type for Store Owner**  or else use following.

[image]

Where **is_free_installation** is unique attribute code.

2)  navigate to **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes Sets** to assign a newly created attribute to a attribute set.

- --> select attribute set (if you don't have any custom set then select Default)
- --> you will be able to view newly created attribute on Unassigned Attributes side.
- --> Drag that attribute under General and save attribute set.

3) Reindex data.

4) Now you will be able to see new drop down in product detail page to mark product as free installation or not.

5) Open `app\design\frontend\<YOUR_PACKAGE>\<YOUR_THEME>\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

and place this code wherever you want

```
<?php
if ($_product->getData('is_free_installation')) {
    echo $_product->getData('is_free_installation');
}
```

For grid Mode place near line no 167 and for list mode place near line no 103

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its wrong decision of creationg attribute. You will need to select value from dropdown in each product to show promotional label.It is time consuming process.

Comment: can you pls come for a chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40180/room-for-shopping-cart-text

Comment: Ashish, Thanks for your Answer, It's the most Easiest way

Comment: @part Manchestor Laljii want to show the details on product basis.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is make system configuration setting in custom module using sytem.xml. You can select one time for all products in listing. whenever you need to stop showing label from product listing you can easily disable label from backend.